# ehcache not working in Tomcat Docker image

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ehcache

I have been given a Java application to containerise.

The application is currently running on a Tomcat8 JRE8 AWS Elasticbeanstalk instance.

However, the application fails to deploy in my Docker image, which is built from an Amazon Linux base image with OpenJDK8 and Tomcat8 installed via RPMs.

The deployment errors relates to Ehcache:

```
Error creating bean with name 'getEhcache' defined in *****: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was null:16: Element <cache> does not allow attribute "maxEntriesLocalHeap".
```

I understand that this error typically arises when there is a config mismatch between Ehcache and the version of Ehcache being used, namely that maxEntriesLocalHeap was introduced in Version 2.10, and if Version 2.10 is not available, this error will occur.

I've checked in the application payload, and the correct jar is available:

```
bash-4.2# pwd
/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib
bash-4.2# ls -la ehcache-*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 8914463 Jan 24 12:27 ehcache-2.10.2.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1006074 Jan 24 12:27 ehcache-core-2.4.5.jar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  124522 Jan 24 12:27 ehcache-spring-annotations-1.2.0.jar
```

The developer has told me that the application is picking up an older version of Ehcache, but I can't see how this is possible in a vanilla Docker image. I think it is a spurious error that is being generated by something to do with permissions or file system access in the Docker container when run.

The ehcache.xml file supplied with the application is:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
     updateCheck="true"
     monitoring="autodetect"
     dynamicConfig="true">

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<cache name="messageCache"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000"
       eternal="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
       timeToIdleSeconds="43200" timeToLiveSeconds="43200"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</cache>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehcache has changed the name of the jar in the course of history. Your conflict comes from having both `ehcache-core-2.4.5.jar` and `ehcache-2.10.2.jar` on your classpath.

Most likely the first one is picked up first and thus you get this invalid attribute error. You will most likely have to remove `ehcache-core-2.4.5.jar` but that may require bumping other dependencies, although Ehcache always tried to preserve backwards compatibility across the 2.x line.

Comment: The answer is correct. As a side note, I would turn `updateCheck` to false if I was you.

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm curious as to why this isn't an issue in the ElasticBeanstalk instance but is an issue in the Docker container.